# How can I dynamically access an object's field value in an LWC template?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm really scratching my head here. The below syntax does not work, specifically in "{o[c.value]}" due to "Template expression doesn't allow computed property access". What is the proper way to dynamically get an object's field by its string name in an HTML Template? All the bind examples I can find in documentation are very simplistic and don't fit this scenario.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <template for:each={columns} for:item="c">
            <th key={c.value}>{c.label}</th>
        </template>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template for:each={objects} for:item="o">
            <tr key={o.Id}>
                <template for:each={columns} for:item="c">
                    <td key={c.value}>{o[c.value]}</td>
                </template>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Expressions do not exist in LWC. Instead, you lay out your data in Arrays and access them that way.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <template for:each={columns} for:item="c">
            <th key={c.value}>{c.label}</th>
        </template>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template for:each={objects} for:item="o">
            <tr key={o.Id}>
                <template for:each={o.fields} for:item="f">
                    <td key={f.fieldName}>{f.value}</td>
                </template>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Which means you need to map your data. Given your columns and your objects, they'd be transformed to arrays.

```
this.objects = this.records.map(
  (record) => ({
    Id: record.Id,
    fields: columns.map(
      (column) => ({ fieldName: column.value, value: record[column.value] })
    )
  })
);
```

This is basically what `lightning-datatable` does behind the scenes for you (although much more complicated).

Here, for each record, we create an object that has the Id, and a fields Array that contains the field name and value for each column.

Comment: Clever as always, fox! Thanks for the help. A bit surprising that such gymnastics are required but I guess this isn't the first time that's true in a JavaScript-based environment.